# How to make a pairwise comparisons matrix out of pairwise comparison values in a dataframe?

Tags: matrix, pairwise

I have a dataframe of kinship values between pairs of individuals (ibd_kinship_df):

names(ibd.coeff_df) # "ID1"     "ID2"     "k0"      "k1"      "niter"   "kinship"

I want to obtain a matrix of pairwise comparisons with the individuals names as headers of the matrix (rows & columns) and the pairwise kinship values in the matrix.

I tried this code as suggested in this post --> [How to make a matrix out of pairwise comparisons in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57793983/how-to-make-a-matrix-out-of-pairwise-comparisons-in-r)

but it didn't work for me, I still got a dataframe and not a pairwise comparison matrix...
see below:

class(ibd.coeff_df) # data.frame
ibd.coeff_matrix = xtabs(kinship ~ ID1 + ID2, data=ibd.coeff_df)

class(ibd.coeff_matrix) # "xtabs" "table" - not a distance/pairwise comparisons  matrix! it still has the same columns as the dataframe (just the selected ones)

What have I done wrong? Any suggestion on how to achieve this in a simple way?
Thanks!
Gabriella

I have this:
head(ibd.coeff_df) # dataframe
ID1       ID2        k0        k1         niter   kinship
1 18SHK0006 18SHK0007 0.4717972 0.3759833   172    0.1701056

I coded this:
ibd.coeff_matrix = xtabs(kinship ~ ID1 + ID2, data=ibd.coeff_df)

I got this:
ibd.coeff_matrix
ID1       ID2           kinship
1 18SHK0006 18SHK0007   0.1701056

I expected this:

```
    ID2
```

ID1           18SHK0007   18SHK0012  ...
18SHK0006 0.170105574
....